# change in text color of typed value ,without changing color of already present value .using css3 or javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, css, colors, maskedtextbox, maskedinput

I have a date text box and in that I have use placeholder which displays dd/mm/yyyy

on click of textbox it display a value="dd/mm/yyyy" ,and for that I have used mask input plugin my query is I want to change the color of the number which I'm typing, keeping remaining content color unchanged.
how can we do this.

Please, see this screenshot for reference.

[image: plz see this screenshot for reference]

I tried on keypress to change color but changes everything present in the input.

Comment: You have to provide some code what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Something cool? 
check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4x79L86L/10/) 
this will change color depends on value on whatever you want

```js
$('.getvalueofinput').keydown(function() {
  var value1, value2;
  value1 = $('.getvalueofinput').val();
  value2 = $('.equalvalue').text();
  if (value1 == value2) {
    alert('equal');
    $('.getvalueofinput').css('background-color', 'brown').css('color','white');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text class="getvalueofinput">
<span class='equalvalue' value='write me'>write me</span>
```

Comment: @ManishaVerma Write " Write Me " if you see that condition you will get it